# How to customize Date Format in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I need to customize the date format in Wordpress. I know that minor date changes can be made from Dashboard << Settings << General << Date. But my needs are not fulfilled from that.

I need that on post page, Month should have different font style and Day with a different font.

Comment: This is changed in the theme, and it all depends which one you use.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to have a different style applied to both the Month and the Day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, one solution would be to wrap each part of the date in a different span class. So whenever you want to insert the date you would use something like the following:

```
<?php the_time('F', '<span class="month">', '</span>'); ?>
&nbsp;
<?php the_time('d', '<span class="day">', '</span>'); ?>
```

Then you can target these different span classes separately in your css.

```
.month {
    font-family:serif;
}
.day {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

This will output a format that looks like this: **April 11** where both the month and date can be styled separately however you want. You can display a different month/date format by changing what you pass into `the_time()` function. For example, changing the month code to `<?php the_time('m', '<span class="month">', '</span>'); ?>` will output **Apr 11** instead.

There are a lot of different configurations for this and there's more info on that here http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time